# how to disable sound on push notification?

Tags: java, android, push-notification

I saw the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#sound):

```
public Uri sound

Added in API level 1
The sound to play.

To play the default notification sound, see defaults.
```

but how do I disable sound playing? sending `Uri == null` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't call setSound(uri) with NotificationBuilder, the sound won't play.
Eg.
The following would play the default sound for notification:

```
Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager
                .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("title")
                .setSound(alarmSound);
```

Just remove ".setSound(alarmSound)" and it won't play the sound, like:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("title");
```

Hope i got the question right(?)

Comment: but then if the default is non mute?

Comment: where is the default set? in device settings by the user? it sounds strange that we can override the user choise

Comment: We arent setting the sound so it wont make one, need to check if the behaviour is different at an O.S. version level

Comment: so how can we play default sound? who choose what is default?

Comment: Default is what the mobile user has set, like the tone for messages, the part of code above with 'alarmSound' fetches the default uri